# Looping though all .sh files in a directory to find specific text in each one

Tags: bash

I have a bunch of .sh files in a directory.  I need to find out how many stored procedures each one of them calls.  What would be the best way to do that?

I'm REALLY new with bash scripts so this is all very new to me.  From what I looked online I hacked up a starting point (I think) but I have no idea how I would open each file, and find "something.sql" in it and then out put number of times that was found in each file.

Here's what I have:

```
#!/bin/sh

for i in 'ls *.sh'
    echo -e "\n **** START****"
    do
      echo -e " \n Filename: $i"
    done
      echo -e "\n **** END ****"
done
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: There is a special command `grep` for this usecase: `grep  -c "something.sql" *.sh`, For more details look it up.

Comment: You are looking through bash scripts just for references to sql files-- or do you need to then look into the sql files for stored procedures.  I'm not sure you are using the term "stored procedures" correctly, or you are just missing info.

Comment: @SaintHax I just need to look into the .sh file and find anything that resembles a reference to a stored procedure.  So anything like sp.sql I'd count it towards that file name once.  if it calls 2-3 stored procedures then that filename will have that many counts for it.

Comment: OK, so and sql statement/script does not make it a stored procedure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

`grep -nc sql *.sh`

See how that moves you.  You can add -i if you name sql files in as file.SQL too.  Or if they all have a .sql extension.

`grep -nc '\.sql' *.sh`

For you comment you added, try this:

```
for i in *.sh
   grep -Hc '\.sql' $i
   grep '\.sql' $i
done
```